# Possible regression in G++ 6.1.0

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cassert>

    struct       AV {
        explicit AV(std::string const&) {}
    };

#if 1
    static void check_cache_item(
        std::map<std::string, std::string> const& items) // FIXME remove
    {
        assert(!items.empty());
    }
#endif
    static void check_cache_item(
        std::map<std::string, AV> const& items)
    {
        assert(!items.empty());
    }


int main()
{
    check_cache_item({ { "id", "0" }, { "pk", "#0" } });
    check_cache_item({ { "id", "0" }, { "pk", "#1" } });
    check_cache_item({ { "id", AV{"0"} }, { "pk", AV{"#1"} } });
}
```

is accepted by g++ 4.8.4, g++ 5.3.0, clang++ 3.9.0; but g++ 6.1.0 gives an error:

```
cci.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
cci.cc:25:55: error: call of overloaded ‘check_cache_item(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
     check_cache_item({ { "id", "0" }, { "pk", "#0" } });
                                                       ^
cci.cc:10:17: note: candidate: void check_cache_item(const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)
     static void check_cache_item(
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cci.cc:16:17: note: candidate: void check_cache_item(const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, AV>&)
     static void check_cache_item(
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cci.cc:26:55: error: call of overloaded ‘check_cache_item(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
     check_cache_item({ { "id", "0" }, { "pk", "#1" } });
                                                       ^
cci.cc:10:17: note: candidate: void check_cache_item(const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)
     static void check_cache_item(
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cci.cc:16:17: note: candidate: void check_cache_item(const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, AV>&)
     static void check_cache_item(
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cci.cc: At global scope:
cci.cc:10:17: warning: ‘void check_cache_item(const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     static void check_cache_item(
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I #ifdef out the first constructor, then every compiler throws an error (rightly, because the AV constructor is explicit).

Is this a regression in G++ 6.1.0 ?

Comment: [Online repro example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0Z1d2KR6anWldz7o)

Comment: G++ 7 (trunk) also reports an error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a surprising and somewhat unfortunate aspect of the Standard (I would go so far as to call it a defect); it is the result of a collision between the overload resolution rules for copy-list-initialization (**[over.match.list]** as confirmed in [CWG 1228](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1228)), and the element-forwarding constructor of `pair` (as per [n4387](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387)).

gcc (>= 6.1.0) is correct to reject your program; clang is incorrect to accept it. Earlier versions of gcc accept your program because they had not yet implemented n4387; clang accepts your program because it [excludes explicit constructors from consideration for overload resolution for copy-list-initialization](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27642), which violates **[over.match.list]** according to the Standard ([Calling an explicit constructor with a braced-init list: ambiguous or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622076/calling-an-explicit-constructor-with-a-braced-init-list-ambiguous-or-not?rq=1))

---

If we peel away the extraneous aspects of your program it comes down to a simple question of overload resolution:

```
struct A { explicit A(int, int); };
struct B { B(int, int); };

void f(A);
void f(B);

int main() { f({0, 0}); }
```

Here `A` is standing in for `pair<std::string const, AV>` and `B` is standing in for `pair<string const, string>`. The constructor of `A` is explicit because pace n4387 it involves the explicit constructor of `AV`; but per CWG 1228 the rules for copy-list-initialization:

> [...] include all constructors but state that the program is ill-formed if an explicit constructor is selected by overload resolution. [...]

[**[over.match.list]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list):

> [...] In copy-list-initialization, if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed. [ *Note:* This differs from other situations ([over.match.ctor], [over.match.copy]), where only converting constructors are considered for copy-initialization. This restriction only applies if this initialization is part of the final result of overload resolution.  *— end note* ]

Thus your program is correctly considered (under the Standard as it currently is) to be ambiguous.

Further reading: [What could go wrong if copy-list-initialization allowed explicit constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157041/what-could-go-wrong-if-copy-list-initialization-allowed-explicit-constructors)

Comment: I'm not sure this is necessarily a defect, though it is somewhat surprising.

Comment: "does not implement CWG 1228" What's there to implement? I thought the result of CWG is the rules written in the standard are correct. There's no proposed change as a result of that, right?

Comment: @T.C. fair enough, though I reserve the right to consider it a defect myself.

Comment: @Barry good point; CWG 1228 just confirmed the current wording. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622076/calling-an-explicit-constructor-with-a-braced-init-list-ambiguous-or-not?rq=1 discusses where it came from and the rationale behind it.

Comment: @ecatmur LOL I forgot that was my question and just tried to upvote it.