# Ambiguous overloads, implicit conversion and explicit constructors

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, default-constructor

Consider the following little program:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class A {
  int a;
  int b;

 public:
  explicit A() = default;
  A(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}

  int f(const A& a) { return 0; }
  int f(std::vector<int> a) { return 1; }
};
int g(const A& a) { return 2; }
int g(std::vector<int> a) {  return 3; }

int main() {
  A a(1,2);
  //   a.f({}); //ambiguous according to gcc
  g({}); //ambiguous according to gcc
  return 0;
}
```

GCC 10.2 refuse to compile it: it says the call to `g({})` and `a.f({})` are ambiguous. Clang compile this without complaining.

It seems to me that `g(const A&)` shouldn't be considered in overload resolution because implicit conversion from no arguments is not allowed: `A::A()` is marked explicit.

I am not confident that the fault isn't mine and, in any case, I'd like to find a workaround.

Is there another default generated constructor that could be the source of my problem?

You can try it on the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:7,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:7,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:7,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:7,startLineNumber:20),source:%27%0A%23include+%3Cfmt/core.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Aclass+A+%7B%0A++int+a%3B%0A++int+b%3B%0A%0A+public:%0A++explicit+A()+%3D+default%3B%0A++A(int+_a,+int+_b)+:+a(_a),+b(_b)+%7B%7D%0A%0A++void+f(const+A%26+a)+%7B+fmt::print(%22A%5Cn%22)%3B+%7D%0A++void+f(std::vector%3Cint%3E+a)+%7B+fmt::print(%22vector%5Cn%22)%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Avoid+g(const+A%26+a)+%7B+fmt::print(%22A%5Cn%22)%3B+%7D%0Avoid+g(std::vector%3Cint%3E+a)+%7B+fmt::print(%22vector%5Cn%22)%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++A+a%3B%0A++//+++a.f(%7B%7D)%3B%0A++g(%7B%7D)%3B%0A++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.738460876672264,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1101,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:fmt,ver:%27700%27)),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+11.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.26153912332775,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+11.0.1%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.26153912332775,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622076/calling-an-explicit-constructor-with-a-braced-init-list-ambiguous-or-not) was brought to my attention. Its answer tells us which compiler is right: it's GCC. But it does not tell us how to obtain the desired behavior with those overload rules.

Comment: I would change default to explicit in title

Comment: I'm not convinced you're right. It seems possible to me that `{}` might be allowed to use an explicit constructor, I'm not sure. It's definitely not an implicit conversion...

Comment: @Yakk done. finding a good title is always a struggle.

Comment: I would say gcc bug. especially when clang/msvc accept it [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9EeM6x).

Comment: with extra `int` argument (instead of default constructor), only clang accepts it [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d8aE18)...

Comment: Interesting, if you comment out `std::vector` variant gcc complains that explicit ctor of `A` cannot be used.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm not convinced i'm right either.

Comment: Btw you could minimize your example removing `class A` members, another ctor, methods etc https://ideone.com/tgyAfg

Comment: If non default ctor is used then gcc compiles just fine - https://godbolt.org/z/P3aYYE

Comment: GCC is correct - see the dup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that it seems like a bug.  The commented out line below fails to compile for the exact reason that there should be no ambiguity.

Got a workaround for you using std::initializer_list:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <vector>

class A {
  int a;
  int b;

 public:
  explicit A() = default;
  A(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {fmt::print("Aab\n");}

  void f(const A& a) { fmt::print("A\n"); }
  void f(std::vector<int> a) { fmt::print("vector\n"); }
  void f(std::initializer_list<int> l) {
      return f(std::vector<int>(l));
  }
};
void g(const A& a) { fmt::print("A\n"); }
void g(std::vector<int> a) { fmt::print("vector\n"); }
void g(std::initializer_list<int> a) {return g(std::vector<int>(a)); }

int main() {
  A a(1,2);
  A a2 = A();
  //A a3 = {};
  a.f({});
  g({});
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. Now i guess i have a bug report to submit.

Comment: Nice find - please share the bug link if you report one.  I'd like to follow along!

Comment: See latest edit, seems it ain't a GCC bug after all.

Comment: OK, I guess I have to concede to Bjarne!